# Proteus simulation error

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, opto-isolator, drive

I am getting these errors while running simulation in proteous.

[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=7.87403e-006

[SPICE] TRAN:  Timestep too small; timestep = 1.25e-019: trouble with node #00004.

Please help me out....

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you didn't connect ground to the negative side of your batteries?

Comment: jepp, I think StarCat is right. Spice simulators do not like missing grounds. Please add 2 GND's - one to each battery - and test if it works

Comment: oh ok, now that ive used common grounds for R3 and Mosfet, its simulating well, but the whole purpose of using an optoisolator is galvanic isolation right.....? my perspective was not to use the Same grounds for both sides of the isolator.....how to give galvanic isolation here........?