# Why doesn't my MOSFET work?

Tags: mosfet, simulation, buck, spice, proteus

This is a circuit that will take any Vin > 5 (through a diode bridge against reverse connection) and buck convert it to 5 volts. But, there is some error related to PMOSFET when I try to simulate it on Proteus.

It gives the error:

[image: Error]

[image: Circuit Scheme]
[image: My Arduino code]

What is wrong with my circuit?

Comment: Try with a real PMOS model instead.

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Try a real NPN model too. Don't use the SPICE default models for things, they  aren't very good for most purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem that is immediately obvious from your schematic is that the arduino does not share a ground with your external circuit. Without such a common ground, (or some special circuitry) you cannot effectively transmit a signal from the arduino to the external circuit.

Comment: Found the question [Proteus simulation error](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522202/proteus-simulation-error) which has the same ``[SPICE] TRAN: Timestep too small; timestep = 1.25e-019:`` error as in this question. The comments in the referenced question indicate adding a common ground stopped the Proteus simulation errors. I don't have Proteus to be able to confirm this.

Comment: Yes, this fixed my problem. I removed the diode bridge and added a ground to the second circuit. When I clicked on Arduino properties, there was a button "Hidden Pins". Arduino ground pin was automatically connected to the ground... As I didn't add a ground in my first version, simulator was giving an error.